Air Handler drain is clear, but bottom of Air handler has water
Last summer I had a plumber rework our AC drain in the attic for our air handler. There is a drain pain angled down toward the drain under the coils. This water is draining and can see the flow. However, beneath the slanted drain is the bottom of the air handler. It has about 1/4 inch of insulation on it. (interior) Its full of water. When looking at the design, there is no where for this water to drain so it just leaks into the pan beneath the handler. The pan below fills up and we have to shop vac it. I thought its strange that the pan beneath the AC doesn't have a drain. So, about once a day I am having to shop vac it down with all the condensation leaking from inside and underneath. I will point out, that the water from the coil pan does drain, but the bottom underneath doesn't. Any idea how to make this stop?

Welcome! We'll need more information about how the water finds its way to the bottom of the air handler case. Is it condensing on the air handler case surfaces directly? Are there drips falling (or blowing) off the evaporator coil and falling to the case, avoiding being caught in the drain pan? Does the drain pan have a crack or otherwise leak? To answer these questions you may have to thoroughly dry the case, run the system for a few minutes, then open it again and observe where the water appears first on the floor of the air handler case.

Where is the "This water is draining and can see the flow" water draining to?
